# Constant acceleration movement with minus acceleration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, game-physics

I making movement process on Unity.

I would like to make a process that moves the object to a specified position, but as the title suggests, I want the object not only to move, but also to reach a predetermined distance with its velocity decaying.

If the acceleration is negative, I can not to process it well.
Specifically, I want to reach a position without turning back when the initial velocity is 10 as shown in the gif.

I used "s=v0t+1/2at^2" from the constant acceleration movement formula to find the acceleration "a", but that does not seem to be enough.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float t;
    public float initSpd;
    public Transform t1, t2;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var p = t1.position;
        while (true) {
            t1.position = p;
            var v0t = initSpd * t;
            var distance = Vector2.Distance(t1.position, t2.position);
            var direction = (t2.position - t1.position).normalized;
            var a = (2 * (distance - v0t)) / (t * t);
            var v = initSpd;
            // update
            yield return Utils.Coroutine.WhileForSeconds(t, () =>
            {
                t1.Translate(direction * v * Time.deltaTime);
                v += a * Time.deltaTime;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

span=3, initial velocity=0
[image: 初速度=0]
span=3, initial velocity=3
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
span=3, initial velocity=10
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math to compute `a` is correct, but you have posed the problem in a way that cannot be solved to your satisfaction.

As you said, with constant acceleration the position is a quadratic function of time, so it is described by

```
s = b t^2 + c t + d
```

for some constants `b, c, d`. The value of `d` is already fixed by the initial position. The value of `c` is already fixed by the initial velocity. There is only one free parameter left, and when you solve for `s(finalTime) = goalPosition`, you can't control whether or not the resulting parabola overshoots the goal or not.

You can increase the polynomial degree, but there will always be some initial velocity that is too large and causes overshoot.

Essentially, you have an optimal control / trajectory optimization problem, something like

```
  minimize: integral(acceleration(t)^2) from t = 0 to T
subject to: x(0) given
            v(0) given
            x(T) given
            x(t) <= x(T) for all t in [0, T] (assuming x(0) < x(T))
```

As you stated the problem, there was no optimization objective, but you need either a cost or a constraint on the acceleration, otherwise you could get solutions with infinite acceleration (e.g. accelerate really hard in the first time step, then coast to the goal at constant velocity).

The inequality makes it complicated. If you want a continuous-time analytic solution, then Pontryagin's principle would be a hammer to solve it, but there might be easier tricks. If you discretize time and let the acceleration be piecewise-constant, then it's an easy convex optimization problem.

If you are willing to relax the "never overshoot" and "get there at exactly this time" constraints, then very simple solution, that will scale better to more complex scenarios like external forces, is to use a feedback control law like a PD controller:

```
a = kp * vectorToGoal - kd * velocityVector,
```

where `kp` and `kd` are hand-tuned positive constants, and this expression is re-evaluated in every frame. You can tune `kp` and `kd` to minimize overshoot in your typical scenarios.

Or, you could do what most games do - allow velocity to change instantaneously :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.
I thought that important to the time to reach, and the distance between the two points is also important.
When the ball is advancing and is given a vertical force from the forward direction, it curves the ball.
Then, I want the curved ball to stop at the position where moving by the amount of distance that I initially calculated.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a linear interpolation like Bezier's curve because it will eventually reach the end point, regardless of the distance.
I updated image, the red line is the distance value.
I figured that if I could get the "a" I want, just needed to change directions at every frames.I still don't fully understand your answer. I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem statement.

What is "a vertical force from the forward direction"?

"I want the curved ball to stop at the position where moving by the amount of distance that I initially calculated" sounds like you want to compute a path from point a to point b with arc length exactly L. If so, why not use circular arcs?

Comment: Try formulating your problem mathematically instead of with words. It will help people here, but more importantly, it will be a useful step towards figuring out the solution on your own.

Comment: Is it perpendicular rather than vertical? For example, it's right or left in relation to up.
I just wanted to find the proper negative acceleration.
It may have been confusing information about the curves I mentioned, sorry.
The ball may expecting to a spiraling motion, not circluring, that difficult to precalculate the trajectory, so I want to know the amount to advance each frame.
And I was taught an answer that uses two constant acceleration movement. 
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/69014/96
It's working well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the ideal behavior achieved by changing the speed in two steps.

```
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var p = t1.position;
        while (true)
        {
            t1.position = p;
            var direction = (t2.position - t1.position).normalized;
            var distance = Vector2.Distance(t1.position, t2.position);

            var v0 = initSpd;
            var M = distance;
            var T = duration;
            var tm = M / v0;
            var vm = v0 / T * tm;
            var accel1 = (vm - v0) / (tm - 0);
            var accel2 = (0 - vm) / (T - tm);
            Debug.Log($"vo={v0}, M={M}, T={T}, tm={tm}, vm={vm}, accel1={accel1}, accel2={accel2}");
            var v = initSpd;
            var stime = Time.time;
            var hist = 0f;
            // update
            yield return Utils.Coroutine.WhileForSeconds(T, () =>
            {
                t1.Translate(direction * v * Time.deltaTime);
                hist += v * Time.deltaTime;
                if (Time.time - stime <= tm)
                    v += accel1 * Time.deltaTime;
                else
                    v += accel2 * Time.deltaTime;
            });
            Debug.Log($"elapsed={Time.time - stime}, moved distance={hist}, v={v}");
        }
    }
```